# conversion sql query to jpa

Tags: jpa-2.0

I have a query

```
SELECT d.name, count(e.id) FROM department d LEFT OUTER JOIN employee e on e.department_id = d.id and e.salary > 5000
```

and how i can convert this to jpa
right now i have:

```
CriteriaQuery<Object[]> criteria = builder.createQuery(Object[].class); 
Root<Department> root = criteria.from(Department.class);
Path<String> name = root.get("name");
Expression<Long> empCount = builder.count(root.get("employees").get("id"));
criteria.multiselect(name,empCount);
TypedQuery<Object[]> query = em.createQuery(criteria);
```

I simplified both examples by removing ordering and grouping
can anyone tell me how i can modifie my jpa code to get same reslults like from my sql query

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not far from the result. The problem is that, AFAIK, you can't add any restriction on the `on` clause, using JPA. So the query wil have to be rewritten as

```
SELECT d.name, count(e.id) FROM department d 
LEFT OUTER JOIN employee e on e.department_id = d.id 
where (e.id is null or e.salary > 5000)
```

Here is the equivalent of this query not tested):

```
CriteriaQuery<Object[]> criteria = builder.createQuery(Object[].class); 
Root<Department> root = criteria.from(Department.class);
Path<String> name = root.get("name");

Join<Department, Employee> employee = root.join("employees", JoinType.LEFT);

Expression<Long> empCount = builder.count(employee.get("id"));
criteria.multiselect(name,empCount);
criteria.where(builder.or(builder.isNull(employee.get("id")),
                          builder.gt(employee.get("salary"), 5000)));

TypedQuery<Object[]> query = em.createQuery(criteria);
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, all what  needed to change was root.joinCollection to root.join

Comment: BTW, what if i want to change my query to selec number of all employees and those who earn more than 5k? shall i do join twice or here is any easer way?