# Convert sql query to JPA. Join 3 tables

Tags: java, mysql, sql, sql-server, jpa

I have a database that currently got 3 tables that i want to join together.
products
product_category
category

I have an sql join that does what i need it to do, which is taking category_id and returning all products in that category.

`SELECT products.name FROM products 
JOIN product_category ON products.id = product_category.product_id 
JOIN categories ON categories.id = product_category.category_id 
WHERE categories.id = ?`

I have tried to google for a while now without success.

How can i make this happen?

Comment: Is this SQLServer or is this MySQL? They are two different relational database systems. One does not mean sql that happens to be on a server and the other does not mean your sql.

Comment: already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7848582/3248346