# Convert To JPA aliased SELECT on a Joined Query

Tags: java, jpa

For the Table Structure :

**QUESTION**

```
id

question
```

**STUDENT**

```
id

name
```

**ANSWER**

```
id

question_id

student_id
```

**Objective :** 
Get All Answered and Unanswered Questions for a Given Student

**SQL tried and tested in MYSQL**

```
SELECT * FROM question q 
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT * FROM answer a WHERE a.student_id=?) AS answered 
ON q.id = answered.question_id;
```

How do you convert this to JPA?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7848582/conversion-sql-query-to-jpa

Comment: Thanks @NishanthiGrashia, but that is not the same. The part where it needs to be converted to JPA is the aliased select. And not JOINS as mentioned on the subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Offset, read on this:

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/partpersist.htm#BNBPY

```
SELECT a.question FROM Answer a WHERE a.student.id = :studentId;
```

If you really want to do it manually using the alias select:

```
SELECT q FROM Question q WHERE EXISTS(SELECT a FROM Answer a WHERE a.question.id = q.id);
```

Comment: the aliased SELECT in LEFT outer join is the question. SELECT a FROM Answers a RIGHT JOIN a.question q WHERE (....) <-- this part is the problem.

Comment: The sql i have there would more or less be converted to the alias select. Its jpa, and there is a direct relationship

Comment: Do you have the whole QL statement? The select statement you mentioned does not show the unanswered question. Please see SQL statement above. Thank you.